# Application fee cost for New Zealand tourist visas

Tags: visas, fees-and-charges, new-zealand, nigerian-citizens

I am Nigerian. If I want to apply for tourist visas for New Zealand, what is the visa fee cost? I see different amounts.

Answer (score 9):

The cost for a visitor visa application for New Zealand varies depending on a number of parameters.

According to the official website https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/visas/visa/visitor-visa a visa application for a single Nigerian citizen applying online from Nigeria currently costs NZ$246.

But based on your previous question history, I wonder if it makes any sense for you to try to apply for one?

Also remember that depending on the chosen route and flights, you may need additional visas for some of the intermediate countries.

Comment: I believe people just want to migrate to another country the right way. Applying for a nigerian passport is seen like Gold - its expensive and takes ages (hearsay)